# Unstructured data to find a column count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I have unstructured data from my perf logs. I would like to capture the service details from it.  I can do delimiter, however I am not able to count or Print the column, since it doesn't have any header.

Kindly help me to figure out this issue.s

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv (r'/Users/Myhome/Documents/Py_Learning/log.csv', sep = '|' , skipinitialspace=True)
#df = pd.read_csv (r'/Users/Myhome/Documents/Py_Learning/log.csv', sep =':|,|[|]', engine='python', header=None) ---> Multi separator is giving error. 


#df.groupby("CLIENT")
SERVICE = df.columns[4]
print (SERVICE)
```

How can I find the unique service name in all lines and get the count. I would like to give it as a graph with last week data.

Sample data :

```
2019-10-22 15:35|Where:CARD|SERVICE:Dell|VERSION:1.0|CLIENT:HDD|OPERATION:boverdue|RESPONSETIME:0034|STATUS:100000:ERR_TRANSACTION_TIMED_OUT|SEVERITY:ERROR|STATUSCODE:SOAP-FAULT|STATUSMESSAGE:NA 2019-10-22 15:35|Where:Digital|SERVICE:Laptop|VERSION:1.0|CLIENT:mouse|OPERATION:connet|RESPONSETIME:3456|STATUS:NO_RECORDS_MATCH_SELECTION_CRITERIA|SEVERITY:INFO|STATUSCODE:1120|STATUSMESSAGE:NA
```

Comment: Did you tried `df[4].unique().count()`. Pleas provide if possible an head of your data.

Comment: nope. let me try

Comment: It wont work, could you provide data sample?

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'unique'

Comment: Did you tried out my answer bellow? It’s better to edit you own question when adding data to the Ques or something related to it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know exactely how is your dataset, but you can return unique values by using `value_counts` [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

```
df_unique = (df['SERVICE'].value_counts()
              .rename_axis('service')
              .reset_index(name='COUNT'))
```